# Norm of a functional on $C[a,b]$

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Could you help me, please with the following question?

I have a linear functional $T : C([a,b]) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that

$$  Tf=\int_{a}^{b}f(t)\varphi(t)dt  $$
where $\varphi$ is a fixed fucntion, $\varphi \in C([a,b])$.
The task is to prove that $$ || T || = || \varphi ||_{\infty} = \max_{a \leq t \leq b} |\varphi(t)|. $$

The norm in $C([a,b])$ is $||f||_{1} = \int_{a}^{b} |f(t)|dt$.

I have already proved that the functional is bounded and $|| T || \leq || \varphi ||_{\infty}$

$\forall f \in C([a,b])$, $ | Tf | = |\int_{a}^{b}f(t)\varphi(t)dt| \leq \int_{a}^{b} | f(t)||\varphi(t)|dt \leq \int_{a}^{b} |f(t)|\max_{a \leq t \leq b} |\varphi(t)|dt = ||\varphi||_{\infty}\int_{a}^{b}\left | f (t) \right |dt = ||\varphi||_{\infty}|| f (t) ||_{1}$.

Now i need to prove the inverse inequality or find a sequence of continuous functions such that $||f_{n}||_{1} = 1$
and  $|Tf_n| \longrightarrow || \varphi ||_{\infty}$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

$\varphi$ is a continuous function on a compact set, so it's sup is attained at some point $y \in [a,b]$. Take a sequence of functions $f_n$ such that $f_n \to \delta_y$, the Dirac mass at $y$. If you are unaware, the Dirac mass satisfies $\int \delta_y\varphi(x) dx = \varphi(y)$, and since $y$ is the point the extrema is attained at, this is your desired sequence of functions.

Comment: Thank you, i will tray.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\varphi$ attains its maximal absolute value at $c \in [a, b]$, i.e. $\varphi(c) = \|\phi\|_\infty$.

For any $\delta > 0$, consider the function $f_\delta \in C([a, b])$ such that $f_\delta(x) = 1_{|x - c| < \delta}$. Note that $\|f\|_1 > 0$.

By continuity of $\varphi$, we know that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta$ such that whenever $|x - c| \leq \delta$, we have $|\varphi(x) - \varphi(c)| \leq \epsilon$, which implies $|\varphi(x)| \geq |\varphi(c)| - \epsilon$.

Therefore we get $\|Tf_\delta\|_1 \geq (|\varphi(c)| - \epsilon)\cdot\|f_\delta\|_1$.

Since the space $C([a, b])$ is dense in $L^1([a, b])$ and $T$ is continuous (being bounded above by $\|\varphi\|_\infty$, as you have shown), there exists a sequence of continuous functions $(f_n)_n$ converging to $f_\delta$ and we have $\lim \|f_n\|_1 = \|f_\delta\|_1$ and $\lim \|Tf_n\|_1 = \|Tf_\delta\|_1$.

Thus by taking $f_n$ for sufficiently large $n$, we get $\|T\| \geq |\varphi(c)| - 2\epsilon$.
This being true for all $\epsilon > 0$, we conclude that $\|T\| \geq |\varphi(c)| = \|\varphi\|_\infty$.

Comment: Your $f_\delta$ is not continuous.

Comment: @ArcticChar Well OK.

Comment: @ArcticChar I fixed the proof with some details omitted. At least it's logically correct now.

Comment: Thank you for the all the details. I will tray to understand it.

Comment: I can't see why $\|Tf_\delta\|_1 \geq (|\varphi(c)| - \epsilon)\cdot\|f_\delta\|_1$ since $|\varphi(x)| \geq |\varphi(c)| - \epsilon$ is only true if $|x - c| \leq \delta$. Could you expand on the point, please?

Comment: @studentmaths Because for $|x - c| > \delta$, the value of $f_\delta$ is zero. Therefore e.g. $\|f_\delta\|_1$ can be written as $$\int_{x \in [a, b], |x - c| \leq \delta} dx$$ and similarly for $\|Tf_\delta\|_1$. The inequality is then clear.